# "He flew his kite on windy days but wished it was/were a drone."

Tags: tense, past-tense, usage, phrases

> He flew his kite on windy days but wished it was a drone.

> He flew his kite on windy days but wished it were a drone.

The use of was and were are confusing as they are shown in the dictionary as being the same.

> The past simple of **be**

When to use was or were in a sentence?

Comment: Hello Barbara.  Have a look at [ask]  When you ask a question like this, please explain why you find this confusing.  You can also tell us what you think the answer is *and why*

Answer (score 1):

> *He flew his kite on windy days but wished it was a drone*. or He flew his kite on windy days but wished it were a drone.
> Q.
> WHICH IS GRAMMATICALLY CORRECT?

---

A. **He flew his kite on windy days but wished it were a drone**. Correctly uses the subjunctive mood; "were" and not "was".

**The rule about the usage of was and were**: use were with expressions that are hypothetical, wishful, imagined, desired, doubtful, and otherwise contrary to fact—that is to say, **not real**.

> The key to understanding **when to use was or were in a sentence** is determining **whether you need to use the subjunctive mood or not**. A verb is in the **subjunctive mood** if it expresses an action or state that **is not reality**. For example, it might be hypothetical, wished for, or conditional.

[image: Past and Subjunctive Verb Tenses]

**Use were** with the second person (**you**), the first person plural (**we**), the second person plural (**you**), or the third person plural (**they**).

However we need to **make a choice about when to use was or were with** the first person singular (**I**) and the third person singular (**he, she, or it**).

> **Use “Were**,” Not “Was,” **for Wishful Thinking**
> A sure sign that you should use the subjunctive is when the word wish is used. A wish is the desire or hope for something that cannot or probably will not happen.

> **I wish I were the winner of the Nobel Prize in Literature.**

**Note**

> These phrases are never correct: I wish I was, I wish it was, he wishes he was, she wishes she was.

Ref [Grammarly Blog](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/was-vs-were/)

**subjunctive**; noun [ S ]   LANGUAGE   specialized, in some languages, **a verb form that refers to actions that are possibilities rather than facts:** Ref CED [subjunctive](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/subjunctive)